# Week Number in Processing?

Tags: processing, week-number

I have been trying to get the week number in Processing but didn't find how to do it.

How can I get the week number in Processing?

Comment: `day()` and `month()` are both valid functions, getting the week shouldn't be too hard to do.

Answer (score 1):

Processing doesn't have a `week()` function out of the box. But the language that Processing is built on does offer more functionality that you can use for more advanced things that aren't already in Processing.

First off, which mode are you using? Are you using Java mode, or are you using JavaScript mode or P5.js? I'm going to assume you're in Java mode.

If so, keep in mind that since Processing is built on top of Java, anything you can do in Java, you can also do in Processing. So if you can't find the function you're looking for in Processing, chances are it exists somewhere in Java.

I recommend googling something like "Java get current week number" for a ton of results.